# Laravel 5.3 file not found in production

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.3 I want to setup a public accessible upload directory so I did this in the `filesystems.php` config file:

```
'disks' => [

    ...

    'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path().'/uploads',
    ],

    ...
```

In the `store` function in FileController.php, I use this to create the file:

```
        // Send file to "uploads" drive, under "announcements" folder.
        $path = $file->store('announcements', 'uploads');

        // Create file in DB
        $originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $uploadedFile = File::create([
            'name' => $originalName,
            'path' => $path,
        ]);
```

And this function to download a file:

```
public function publicDownload(Request $request)
{
    $file = File::where('path', $request->p)->firstOrFail();

    return response()->download('uploads/'.$request->p, $file->name);
}
```

> This works in the development environment (homestead), but does not work in the production environment (shared host). What is wrong with the code or setup?

Laravel.log says:

```
[2017-08-28 10:46:41] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException' with message 'The file "uploads/announcements/ee00ed45f3354894205c2ae47bb5b30a.pdf" does not exist' in /home3/xxx/app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php:37
```

Comment: Have you checked such directory structure in your production server ?

Comment: @SagarGautam Thanks for asking -- yes, I did check and the files are uploaded with the exact same structure. Strange thing is, when I type in the file path in the browser, it still says "file not found". In development, I can get the file by typing the path directly to the browser.

Comment: While project is updated in the server, sometime empty directory are not considered and not uploaded. In this case you have  to create folders in production. Please check it in your server if `uploads/...` exists.

Comment: @SagarGautam Thanks. I confirm the files and folders exist in production (created successfully, after the first upload).

Comment: Then other things seem okay there.  May be some cache problem. Clear the cache

Comment: Unfortunately running `artisan cache:clear` doesn't help..

Comment: I'm taking about configuration, so try `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Still no luck, @SagarGautam -- I tried all including `config cache`, `config:clear`, `route:clear`, `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Really strange problem then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152980/discussion-between-john-doe-and-sagar-gautam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just noticed you have problem with your root in following line,

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path().'/uploads',
],
```

You have defined root up to `..../public/uploads/` so your full path of file starts form the `..../public/uploads/` and search for file in directory `..../public/uploads/upload/` which doesn't exits.

So change your root to public path only like,

```
    'root'   => public_path(),
```

Another thing,

In download, you are not using Storage Facade, so you need to provide full path like,

```
return response()->download(public_path().'/uploads/'.$request->p, $file->name);
```

Hope you understand.